# How to correctly iterate over all long type range

Tags: c#

If I'd like to loop over all long's range, I would ingenually do:

```
for (long i = long.MinValue; i <= long.MaxValue; ++i)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But it loops forever!

For example, if I do:

```
for (byte b = byte.MinValue; b <= byte.MaxValue; ++b)
{
    // Do something
}
```

It loops forever too, but I solved like this:

```
for (int i = byte.MinValue; i <= byte.MaxValue; ++i)
{
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(i);

    // Do something
}
```

1. With `long` type how can I do?
2. With `long` type how can I achieve the same if I don't increment by 1, but of an higher distance?
3. Are those "ideas" to loop over a type range correct, are there some issues to be warned about, or can I do it better?

Comment: Are you sure you want to loop over all long:s? Even if you loop over one trillion per second, it's still going to take about 585 years to get through them.

Comment: In the real case I will "jump", I will not do ++i. I asked the question just for the sake of curiosity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first two examples, the loop continues forever due to number range overflows.

When `i` (1st example) or `b` (2nd example) exceed the maximum value that can be stored in `long` (1st example) or `byte` (2nd example), their value overflows to the smallest value storable by that type and the loop starts over and over.

Remember: in a `for`-loop, first the loop condition is checked, then the counter increments. If the counter overflows during the increment, the subsequent loop condition check still evaluates to `true`.

To get your example working, try:

```
for (long i = long.MinValue; ; i++) 
{
    if (i == long.MaxValue)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to increment in larger steps, try:

```
const long step = 90000000000;

for (long i = long.MinValue; i <= long.MaxValue; )
{
    // check if loop counter overflows when incrementing by the step
    if (unchecked (i + step) < i)
    {
         break;
    }
    // otherwise it is safe to increment it
    else
    {
         i += step;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't increment by one?

Comment: The condition `i <= long.MaxValue` is always going to be true. You should also probably write the if condition in the second example as `unchecked(i + step) < i` to make it explicit that you are relying on the wraparound behaviour, and to avoid exceptions if the code is compiled with overflow checking turned on.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if anyone knows how long would we expect the example of incrementing by one to take on a modernish machine from 2020? Minutes? Hours? Days?

Comment: @ztech iterating through int (which is 2^32) with an empty for-cycle in C# takes about 7 seconds on my i7-8850H. Long is 2^64, so 7s * 2^32 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 ~= 953, so about a thousand years

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) when you try to increment past `MaxValue`.  You could try this instead:

```
long i = long.MinValue;
do
{
    // Do something
} while (i++ != long.MaxValue);
```

This way, the value of `i` is checked *before* it's incremented, and the loop terminates correctly.

Comment: I like this approach although you should include the i++ statement within the loop and have while(i != long.MaxValue) otherwise you'll miss the last value and therefore have an off by one error :)

Comment: What if I don't increment by one?

Comment: @DanielSiebert I don't think you do miss the last value... `i` doesn't change until *after* the condition check, so when the check fails (because `i == long.MaxValue`), it already had that value for the last iteration.

Comment: @FrancescoB. Then you'll have to check manually in the body of the loop, I think.

Comment: @WillVousden I just ran it to validate, you're right. Both work, but I can say that mine saves you one iteration of the loop ^.^ But the difference between 2^64 and 2^64-1 really won't matter!

Comment: You should probably write the while condition as `(unchecked(i++) != long.MaxValue)` - this indicates to the reader that this algorithm does depend on having the variable wrap around, and will avoid an exception in the case that the code is compiled with overflow checking on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep your loop pattern the same and avoid the overflow:

```
for (BigInteger i = long.MinValue; i <= long.MaxValue; ++i)
{
    // Do something
}
```

I haven't benchmarked it, but I would imagine there would be a noticeable performance penalty for doing it this way.